# How to produce file i/o buffer on linux and other test?

Tags: linux, testing

I want to test my app with file i/o buffer overflow and other I/O error. 
How can I produce such type of cases using programming ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a fuzz testing tool like [zzuf](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/zzuf) to corrupt the input to the program.  This will help simulate IO errors.

More broadly, you are after a [fault injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault_injection) tool (of which a fuzzer is one type).